# Is the process Markov or not?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process

Consider the stochastic process with $X_0=0$ and

$$
X_t=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ for } \ \ t<\tau_1 \\
1 & \text{ for } \ \ \tau_1\leq t < \tau_1+\tau_2 \\
2 & \text{ for } \ \ \tau_1+\tau_2\leq t 
\end{cases}
$$
where the $\tau_i\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1]$ are i.i.d uniform on $(0,1].$

My conclusion: This is **not** a Markov process. Of course it's a valid stochastic process that has some nice properties, e.g. $X_0=0$, it makes two jumps, and with certainty $X_t=2$ for $t\geq 2$.

**Question:** Is that conclusion correct? And does it follow from the work below?

I want to show that
$$
P(X_{T+s}\in A\mid X_t \text{ for } t\leq T)= P(X_{T+s}\in A\mid X_T) \quad\text{ ($1$) }
$$
does not always hold.

For example, let $A=\{2\}$, $T=s=0.5$. If we know the complete dynamics of the process up to time $T=0.5$, then we know the exact value of $\tau_1$, i.e. we know the exact moment the process jumped to state $1$. Let that time be $u\leq 0.5$ so that $X_{0.5}=1$. The left side of $(1)$ is
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X_{1}=2\mid X_t \text{ for } t\leq 0.5, X_{0.5}=1)
&=P(\tau_2\leq 1-u \mid\tau_1=u)\\
&= \int_{0}^{1-u} \ ds =1-u .
\end{aligned}
$$
We can stop here, as $u$ is the specific fixed value of $\tau_1$ for the process.  I.e. the result depends precisely on when the first jump occurred. Thus we conclude that this is not a Markov process. However, we'll go ahead and calculate the right side of $(1)$ in this case:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(X_{1}=2\mid X_{0.5}=1)
&=P(\tau_1+\tau_2\leq 1 \mid\tau_1\leq 0.5)\\
&=\int_0^{0.5} P(\tau_2\leq 1-u \mid\tau_1=u) \ du\\
&= \int_0^{0.5}1-u \ du = \frac{3}{8}.
\end{aligned}
$$

This shows that the Markov property is not satisfied.

Comment: Yes. And yes. $ $

Comment: Much obliged. Cheers.